# Create dynamic report

Tags: .net, image, dynamic, report

I need to create a dynamic report.

The report needs to allow:

Before the report generation
* add unknown number of images with text note.

After the report generation:
* remove image by right click.
* edit the text note by clicking on it.

Somebody knows about some report for C# that has those options?

thanks,
Ofir

Comment: Isn't every report "dynamic"?  You'd use a photocopier otherwise.  Update your question to mention the report generator you use and explain why it is important to remove something after the report was printed.

Comment: i now use in the reportviewer but i need ability to edit the report after i generate it

Answer (score 1):

There's no report in C# which has these options. You will have to write something yourself if you want these features. As far as report generation goes, reporting services (or simply the reportviewer control) is a great way to create a report and format it.

The reportviewer control requires you to provide a datasource which (like most databound controls) can be a list. If you write the code (asp .net or winforms) to populate a list with image urls and text notes, it is straightforward to use this list as a dataset in conjunction with the reportviewer control.

I can provide more details if this sounds like its an option for you